# How to pass parameters in eval in an object form?

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I have this json, and when i get this json i need to run the function which comes at callback object.

```
{
  formId: 'snn_service_item_form',
  item_id: '1',
  item_title: 'some item',
  item_description: '',
  item_duration: '10',
  item_price: '120',
  item_level_1: 1,
  item_level_2: 0,
  item_level_3: 1,
  item_type: 'p',
  callback: {
    callbackName: 'getServices',
    callbackParams: {
      _param1: 1,
      _param2: 2
    }
  }
}
```

so according to this i need to run this:

```
getServices(1,2);
```

i can do that with eval function like:

```
eval(json.callback.callbackName+'(\''+ json.callback.callbackNParams._param1 +'\',\''+ json.callback.callbackNParams._param2 +'\')');
```

i can automate this by putting it into a for in and writing parameters to a string, but i dont think this is the best way to go.

is there a way to assign function name from a var and giving its parameters as an object, in my case like:

```
json.callback.callbackName(json.callback.callbackParams);
```

i know this is not the way to do it but it is what i want to learn.

Thanks, Sinan.

Comment: thanks for the answers, i'll work on call and apply to get that running.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depends on where the function to call is defined (global scope or a local scope).

If global, you don't need `eval` (and it's safer to avoid it), you just reference the function through the global `window` object:

```
var args = [];
for(var p in json.callback.callbackParams) {
    args.push(json.callback.callbackParams[p]);
}
window[json.callback.callbackName].apply(null, args)
```

See the [`apply()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply) used above.

If it's in a local scope, then you need the `eval` (how you have it is fine).

Comment: For a local scope, you could use the `eval` just to get the function object, and then still use the more-reliable `apply` to call it. BTW it's not guaranteed that `for(in)` will return the params in the order you want.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use eval. You can get a reference to a named global variable or function from the `window` object:

```
var callbackfunction= window[json.callback.callbackName];
```

And trying to serialise your values to a string just to have them parsed back to JavaScript unreliably is silly. Call the function explicitly:

```
callbackfunction.call(window, json.callback.callbackParams.param1, json.callback.callbackParams.param2);
```

(`window` here is a dummy value for `this` for when you're not using object methods.)

Better for automating it to accept any number of parameters would be to turn callbackParams into a plain Array:

```
callbackParams: [1, 2]
```

and then use `apply` to call the function:

```
callbackfunction.apply(window, json.callback.callbackParams);
```

Comment: `func.call(null, ...)` will give you the same (well, almost) behavior as `func.call(window, ...)` — invoking function with `this` value being global object. It's shorter, although probably less descriptive for beginners.