# Pass in vars to an eval workaround to process a code string from a json object after YUI compression

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yui, eval

I need to pass a jQuery object in to a workaround for an eval.  The issue is that i need access to a jQuery object that is out side the eval area but i can't see to pass it in.  here is what i have.

```
var  jObj = $(selector);
var myCode = "var jObj="+jObj+"; var i="+i+"; "+shape.mouseover.onEnd.replace("\u0027","'");
var myFucn = new Function(myCode);
myFucn();
```

the oject I'm getting the string out of is

```
shape.mouseover.onEnd.replace("\u0027","'");
```

is working and what I'm passing in that string is

```
open_info(jObj,i)
```

Which is what i have to fire.  The deal is that the code is run thru YUI compressor so the jObj var becomes something else so i need to pass that in.  Right now i get an error where it thinks it should have and ending ] which is not right.  I is working it seems, just not the jObj var.

**EDIT**

there are many way to get where i need to be that are close but not quite like 
[How to pass parameters in eval in an object form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500745/how-to-pass-parameters-in-eval-in-an-object-form)

```
shape.mouseover.onEnd = "open_info(jObj,i)";
/*
 * this is coming in and must be as it is, don't say it's wrong please
 * it's not able to be done anyother way!
 */


//lets process the string and pull in the vars
/* BEOFRE YUI COMPRESSOR CHANGES THINGS and works!!!
    var  jObj = $(selector);
    var i = 1;
    var myCode = shape.style.events.mouseover.onEnd.replace("\u0027","'");
    var myFucn = new Function(myCode); 
    myFucn();
 */
// AFTER note it can be random as i change code so it fails cause 
// var jObj is now var r and var i is now var e
    var  r = $(selector);
    var e = 1;
    var p= shape.style.events.mouseover.onEnd.replace("\u0027","'");
    var f=  new Function(p);
    f();
```

Now it works before the compression.. After is not due to the change.  Hope tha tclears it up some

Comment: why are you using `eval`? maybe you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Why are you using `new Function`?  Why not just make a normal function? `var myFucn = function(){}`

Comment: A jQuery object cannot be converted to a string. It becomes `"[object Object]"` which may be referring to your `]` error. Your example is a bit odd - why not just run that code instead of converting it to a string, using `new Function` and calling it directly?

Comment: I'm with Joseph.  It's hard to tell without seeing your code in context, but it looks like what you're wanting to use is a closure.

Comment: jObj when converted to a string is `"[object Object]"` the only thing you can do here is `var jObj = "$(" + selector + ")"` and hope it selects the right element.

Comment: @KevinB: Or ya know, not use `new Function` :-P

Comment: @Rocket Of course, for a lot of questions on SO something similar can be said. :)

Comment: You're doin it wrong? Why would you declare the variables in a string, and in the next line try to evaluate those variables as code, and not just build the variables right away ?

Comment: So, what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Ok, first I'm not using eval, and The goal here is i have to take code that is in a string (this is the way it's coming no chaning it) and i need to eval it but, i have to grab a var that is in the same scoope as the eval'ed string,which i can make all work, but the kicker here is that YUI comrpressor changes the var names so the string is always off.  I think Kevin B is the only one that understands and I bet is right at that to.

Comment: tk for the one that -1 a legit question.. productive.  So @Kevin B that didn't work.  Good thought on being out of the box but it still gave the same .. Really everyone.. what we are looking for is the way to pass a var to the function.. I've seen it for the eval() but.. i was trying to work around that.

Comment: Oops, I had a typo. try this: `var jObj = "$('" + selector + "')"` I missed the quotes

Comment: @Rocket I edited the question to highlight the issue better i hope

Comment: @KevinB yeah i cuahgt that too but it didn't work new error thou..  Error: Invalid value for property <map>: [object Object]

Comment: Why is `shape.mouseover.onEnd` a string?

Comment: Why can't you do `var myFucn = function(){open_info(jObj,i);}`?

Comment: it's coming thru a json feed.. i have no controll over this.  I has to be this way.  Trust me I'd avoid it if i could.

Comment: What does `selector` contain?

Comment: open_info(jObj,i) is in the feed .. so your suggest would end up as var myFucn = function(){shape.mouseover.onEnd } which taks me back to the same spot as the YUI compress changes var jObj and var i

Comment: @KevinB $(selector); was just to simplfy the question to the sore of the issue at the hopes to keep at bay the trolls of the forums from -1 the question.. didn't work :-\  The edit is what is going on where shape.mouseover.onEnd is the json feed parsed to the object

Comment: @KevinB just so it's clear too.. i hard coded it as a test so i ran var myCode = "var jObj=$('#selector'); var i="+i+"; "+shape.mouseover.onEnd.replace("\u0027","'"); which didn't work and throw that error

Comment: thanks everyone for the help, the solution is what i accepted below.  If it has clicked for you on the validity of the issue and you downvoted this question, for the sake of others please correct your mistake as it's only a downvote of miss understanding.  It is perfectly normal to have a onClick="" in html and this is just a parallel to that!  If things are not clear let me fix that but the issues is not invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand why this question got 2 down votes, but well it's solved and works great.  The trick is to do the same manipulation of the dom state.  It's really simple once it is placed out.

```
//so this is what the object is parsed out to from the json string
//since you can't just pass a function stright that way any how
shape.mouseover.onEnd = "open_info(jObj,i)"; 

//this is what will take that string and process it
//note jObj is what is in the orgain code but it changes to 
// var r or something else that is shorter after going thru YUI compressor
// Which is why we can't just use open_info(jObj,i) and it work.. 
// ie: it's not an issue with scoope but an issues with var names being shortened
(function(){
    //this is the trick on passing them so YUI doesn't get them
    //use a string and YUI skips it so we directly create the
    //needed oject in the window namespace 
    window['jObj']=jObj; window['i']=i;
    var p= shape.mouseover.onEnd;
    var f=  new Function(p); 
    f();
})();
```

That is it.. I put it in a click or hover event so it's kin to an onClick.

```
/* EXMAPLE OUTPUT AFTER YUI COMPRESSION
//Note after the YUI compressor get ahold of that 
//processing code above it'll look like 
*/
function(){window.jObj=n,window.i=t;var u=i.mouseover.onEnd,r=new Function(u);r()}();
```

So the way that works is, I needed to fix the issue of the var jObj being renamed.  So I simply made a sting for the name and let the compressed the var name fill the name of the object I need for the processed code string.  Don’t know why I didn’t see it before and I would have saved my rep value :-\ .. oh well.  May be a way to shorten this but I'm leaving it for now.

**Edit**

I recant the edit it was working. :) Very well.. Left wondering what any other ways there would be to make it do the same thing.

Comment: This is a, well, *special* way of doing things, but if it works then it's fine, I guess. (Though I'm not sure why you're passing arguments to the function that doesn't actually accept any.)

Comment: ha yeah fully a left over before i pasted it.  I cleared that off.

Answer (score 0):

I might be going down the wrong tracks and be confused here..

But isnt this what your trying to do?

Send myFucn the correct object and what ever i is

```
myFucn($(selector),10);

function myFucn(jObj,i)
{
shape.mouseover.onEnd.replace("\u0027","'");
}
```

Comment: this will not work, myFucn($(selector),10);  would be in the shape.mouseover.onEnd string.  when function myFucn(jObj,i) goes thru YUI compressor it'll come out as function p(r,e)  so it'd fail

Comment: thats fine? function p(r,e) is the same as myFucn(jObj)

Comment: yes it would act the same.. now that doesn't mean that the next time it's compressed it'll be that same replacements. or this question would not be here lol.. tk --

Comment: But surely if your using a good compressor it shouldnt not affect the code?

Comment: lol. it's YUI .. it's concidered one of the best.  It's all about the fact that and embed snipit of code is injected with some check from a locked json feed.

Comment: Maybe your coding needs refractored or a differnt approach if this is the case?

Comment: no it's just that it's two separated ends of a dom manipulation that takes a json feed and needs to process the code string embed in the parsed object verses the part that is being compressed.  The other option here would be to have some sort of hold on the var names for the compressor.. but that seems not to be able to be done.  But I have the solution below now :D .. tk for the help you and all here. :D